# Display only one line in the placeholder of a TextInput

Tags: react-native

I would like to limit to one line the placeholder of a text input. The content of the placeholder is displayed on two lines.

I allready specified the numberOfLines, multiline to false, and it works only for the content, not the placeholder.

I tried to add a specific height, but it doesn't work.

Some of you have ideas ? Do you think I need to open an issue on github ?

If I don't find a solution, I will code an ellipsis mode to cut manually the text.

Actual version :

```
"expo": "^32.0.6",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Regards.

Comment: React native 0.60 still that trouble happens

Comment: I am facing same issue on 0.60.5 too.